# Is there any way data exchange between Unity and Thingsboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I'm studying at university and our project is to work on the data exchange between Unity and Thingsboard. We already have a physical machine connected to the things board.
But I can't find anywhere how to thingsboard connect to the unity in real time...I wish if we can get a manual about it or something related to it will be great thank you!

Comment: Is there any way -> As long as your two applications at some point allow for export/import data there is **always** a way ;) What about some sockets (TCP/UDP) or HTTP requests etc?

Comment: Thank you! I will also try this way as well. Is there any guide for sockets (TCP/UDP) or HTTP requests? If I find that it will be great

Answer (score 0):

There is no official data exchange between Unity and ThingsBoard, but you could use the general-purpose HTTP API:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/

Comment: Thank you sir I will try to use this method!